# Groovy (Grails) named parameters constructor doesn't set superclass fields

Tags: grails, groovy, superclass, named-parameters

New to Groovy. So I have a superclass

```
class AbstractClass {
User user
}
```

and a subclass

```
class Category extends AbstractClass {
String name
}
```

when I try to create object in the BootStrap.groovy (I'm using Grails) like:

```
User user1 = new User(...).save(failOnError: true)
// I know user1 is properly created
def category1 = new Category(User: user1, name: 'alice').save(failOnError: true)
```

Well, my problem is user field is not being set. It's null. This has been changed: previously, instead of saving the User, I just saved its id (Long id) and it was working. Is there any magic I'm missing here?

When I change the code to:

```
def category1 = new Category(User: user1, name: 'alice')
category1.setUser user1
category1.save(failOnError: true)
```

it works nicely, so I guess there must be something I'm missing here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It might be a possibility that in the first case grails is not persisting the User to the database, it could just be in the Hibernate Session - can you try adding flush:true to you save statement for the User and see if that works? eg. new User(...).save(flush:true, failOnError:true)

Comment: Thanks bschipp, but it was a typo. User should be user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
class AbstractClass {
  User user
}
```

the class has a property whose *name* is `user` (small u) and whose *type* is `User` (capital U), therefore

```
new Category(User: user1, name: 'alice')
```

should be

```
new Category(user: user1, name: 'alice')
```

to match the property name.  Remember Groovy, like Java, is case sensitive.

Comment: Crap!! Typo. Thanks, I've lost half an hour of my life with this.